# Ecto mutliple repos-- how to ignore one for migrations

Tags: ecto

I have an app configured

```
config :my_app,
  ecto_repos: [MyApp.Repo, MyApp.LegacyRepo]
```

MyApp.Repo's migrations are managed by Ecto.
MyApp.LegacyRepo migrations are handled by Rails and error out on `mix ecto.migrate`

Is there a way to specify "I have two repos, but please ignore the second for migrations"?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to change your `config.exs`. Change it to...

```
config :my_app, ecto_repos: [MyApp.Repo]
```

According to [the ecto.migrate documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.html)...

> The repositories to migrate are the ones specified under the
>   :ecto_repos option in the current app configuration. However, if the
>   -r option is given, it replaces the :ecto_repos config.

Not having a MyApp.LegacyRepo in ecto_repos doesn't prevent reads or writes or anything else you'd expect. It just configures the migration task.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a repo into mix ecto.migrate like this

```
mix ecto.migrate -r MyApp.Repo
```

You can update test/test_helper.ex in a phoenix app to only run one repo migrations like this

```
Mix.Task.run "ecto.migrate", ["-r", "MyApp.Repo", "--quiet"]
```